# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [12600, 4200]

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

In this code I am doing a time series split then using scikit learn I am creating a SVR model for prediction. My code is:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing as pre 
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler



X_feature = wind_speed

X_feature = X_feature.reshape(-1, 1)## Reshaping array to be 1D from 2D

y_label = Power
y_label = y_label.reshape(-1,1)

timeseries_split = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=3)
for train1, test1 in timeseries_split.split(X_feature):

    print("Training data:",train1, "Testing data test:", test1)
train1 = train1.reshape(-1,1)## Reshaping array to be 1D fron 2D
test1 = test1.reshape(-1,1)

timeseries_split = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=3)
for train, test in timeseries_split.split(y_label):
    print("Training data_1:",train, "Testing data test_1:", test)

scaler =pre.MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1)).fit(train1)


scaled_wind_speed_train = scaler.transform(train1)
print("scaler", scaled_wind_speed_train)
scaled_wind_speed_test = scaler.transform(test1)

SVR_model = svm.SVR(kernel='rbf',C=100,gamma=.001).fit(scaled_wind_speed_train,train)

y_prediction = SVR_model.predict(y_label)


    print (y_prediction)
    SVR_model.score(scaled_wind_speed_test,train)
```

The error that I am receiving is:

```
Training data: [   0    1    2 ... 4197 4198 4199] Testing data test: [4200 4201 4202 ... 8397 8398 8399]
Training data: [   0    1    2 ... 8397 8398 8399] Testing data test: [ 8400  8401  8402 ... 12597 12598 12599]
Training data: [    0     1     2 ... 12597 12598 12599] Testing data test: [12600 12601 12602 ... 16797 16798 16799]
Training data_1: [   0    1    2 ... 4197 4198 4199] Testing data test_1: [4200 4201 4202 ... 8397 8398 8399]
Training data_1: [   0    1    2 ... 8397 8398 8399] Testing data test_1: [ 8400  8401  8402 ... 12597 12598 12599]
Training data_1: [    0     1     2 ... 12597 12598 12599] Testing data test_1: [12600 12601 12602 ... 16797 16798 16799]
scaler [[0.00000000e+00]
 [7.93713787e-05]
 [1.58742757e-04]
 ...
 [9.99841257e-01]
 [9.99920629e-01]
 [1.00000000e+00]]
/home/nbuser/anaconda3_501/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:475: DataConversionWarning: Data with input dtype int64 was converted to float64 by MinMaxScaler.
  warnings.warn(msg, DataConversionWarning)
[6153.41834275 6006.33852041 5997.57462806 ... 6569.44075144 6393.55696288
 6112.57831243]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-925646f8c16a> in <module>()
     43 
     44 print (y_prediction)
---> 45 SVR_model.score(scaled_wind_speed_test,train)
     46 
     47 

~/anaconda3_501/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in score(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    385         from .metrics import r2_score
    386         return r2_score(y, self.predict(X), sample_weight=sample_weight,
--> 387                         multioutput='variance_weighted')
    388 
    389 

~/anaconda3_501/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/regression.py in r2_score(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight, multioutput)
    528     """
    529     y_type, y_true, y_pred, multioutput = _check_reg_targets(
--> 530         y_true, y_pred, multioutput)
    531 
    532     if sample_weight is not None:

~/anaconda3_501/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/regression.py in _check_reg_targets(y_true, y_pred, multioutput)
     73 
     74     """
---> 75     check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred)
     76     y_true = check_array(y_true, ensure_2d=False)
     77     y_pred = check_array(y_pred, ensure_2d=False)

~/anaconda3_501/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    202     if len(uniques) > 1:
    203         raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"
--> 204                          " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
    205 
    206 

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [12600, 4200]
```

I believe the error my be at : `SVR_model.score(scaled_wind_speed_test,train)` but I do not know how to resolve this. I have edited the indentations to the exact original but am not sure if any unintentional indentations may be causing an error.

Comment: Hi! Can you indent the code in the question so to make it more readable? Also, there are clearly some newlines missing, adding them will help people to understand and answer. Also, is the problematic line `SVR_model.score(scaled_wind_speed_test,train)`? That should be readable from the details in the error message: specifying _where_ you get that error also will help people answering you!

Comment: @MohammedKashif Hi, I have added the complete error trace

Comment: @DavideFiocco I am unsure about what newlines could be missing? I did not update this as I am unsure? I could add these if I could be directed?

Comment: Is the indentation you have posted here in the ques correct, I mean is it exactly the same as on our system ?

Comment: @Asif.Khan thanks for reformatting the code. Still, there is a lot going on there, and that makes it hard to give an answer. For instance, where is `X_feature` defined? It's not clear to me what are the `for` loops supposed to do - at least with this indentation. Are the `train` and `test` variables used? Try maybe to simplify the code and cut inessential bits. The error you are getting is possibly because `score` wants in input 2 variables with an equal number of rows http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html#sklearn.svm.SVR.score so you may want to look into that.

Comment: @MohammedKashif I have uploaded the exact original and this code is exactly the same as my code. Thank you

Comment: @DavideFiocco. I have uploaded my exact code. Apologies for the in correct format of upload. The number of rows are identical but the data has been split into training and testing and when I plot my data I did not expect to see this error.

Comment: @Asif.Khan are you _sure_ shapes are compatible? You can check with `np.shape(scaled_wind_speed_test)` and the same for `train`. In general `score` wants an array of samples X and true values y (see docs), so with it you'd compare wind and power _in the same set_ i.e. not mixing train and test in the arguments of `score`.

Answer (score 2):

The following line should fix the error, assuming I have understood your code correctly

```
SVR_model.score(scaled_wind_speed_test,test)
```

Comment: thank you so much! IThis has given me an output! I just wanted to also ask, how would I be able to plot both my y_prediction and y_label on one graph?